# ANAME record not accepted

Tags: domains, dns, godaddy

I created a application on fleek.co and want to connect my GoDaddy domain to my application. The fleek UI tells me to add an ANAME record with an alias as DNS entry. The GoDaddy UI tells me this is not possible since only IP addresses are allowed as targets. I can't add it as CNAME either because for CNAME entries "@" is not allowed as name.

What is the correct way to enter this DNS record then?

Fleek instructions:

[image]

Go Daddy error message:

[image]

**Update:**

GoDaddy seems not to support ANAME entries. I therefore tried to set it up in AWS Route 53. It only lets me add a PTR or SPF record with a blank subdomain and an alias. Both are not working

[image]

**Update:**

I managed to setup the domain by using the DNS settings of cloudflare.com

Comment: You are setting an `A` record at GoDaddy, not an `ANAME` or `ALIAS` record.  Have you checked that they actually support those?  Most DNS hosts do not.

Comment: I thought they mean A records with ANAME. I cant select them at GoDaddy so I guess they don't support it. Is there any workaround then to make that work?

Comment: You can change DNS hosts.  Duplicate your record set at some other host, and the change your `NS` at GoDaddy to point to your new DNS host.

Comment: Do you know any host that supports ANAME? All I checked did not support it

Comment: AWS Route 53, Cloudflare and Namecheap all support some version of it, although they call it different things.

Comment: I experimented with AWS Rout 53 (details see my updated question). The interface only lets me add PTR and SPF entries with a blank subdomain. Both are not working. What would be the correct option here?

Comment: Use the newer `HTTPS`/`SVCB` records, even if not standard fully yet, they exist since 2 years, and both DNS hosting companies (some of them) and browsers know how to use them.

Comment: The Fleek instructions are also not 100% very useful as they ask you to do a `CNAME` if nothing else works, yet the text given is for the apex of the zone, the one specific record where you can NOT have a `CNAME`...

Comment: `PTR` and `SPF` (which in turn doesn't exist anymore as a record type, it should be `TXT`) have nothing to do with your problems, so trying any record type in random might not be the ideal path to follow for DNS problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting an A record at GoDaddy, not an `ANAME` or `ALIAS` record. GoDaddy does not support those record types. Most DNS hosts do not.

You have a couple options:

#### Use `www`

You can set a `CNAME` for to Fleek using the `www` subdomain. Then you can find some other way of redirecting the domain apex to www.  You could find a 3rd party service that does such redirects and use an `A` record to point to them.

#### Switch DNS hosts

Many DNS hosts support `ANAME` or `ALIAS` records. AWS Route 53, Cloudflare, and Namecheap all support some version of it, although they call it different things.

Since you have tried Route53 and run into problems, here are more specific instructions for it.  You need to choose `CNAME` and then use the option to make it an `Alias`:

[image]

#### Use a CDN

A Content Delivery Network sits between your server an your users as a proxy.  You can usually specify your origin server as a name rather than an IP address.  The CDN handles your DNS which points to the CDN edge nodes which fetch content from the origin and cache it.

Comment: It worked for me by using AWS Route 53

Answer (score 0):

you can use aws globalaccelerator with ELB,if you used elb with globalaccelerator,you can get two static ip address.

Comment: Hi bluce, it's difficult to understand the relevance of this answer to the question that was asked. Answers are expected to be substantive and explanatory. Please add additional details to your answer so that it's clear how it addresses the question about how to properly enter a DNS record on GoDaddy. Thanks!