# How do you configure the root domain on AWS Amplify with GoDaddy domain?

Tags: dns, domain-registration, godaddy, amazon-aws

I have successfully updated the CNAME values to connect my domain to my AWS AMPLIFY static website. There is just one part I need some assistance with.

AWS documentation says the following...

> 1. Configure root domain In order to use your root domain you must configure an ANAME record (also called an ALIAS) in your DNS provider.
>    If your DNS provider does not support ANAME/ALIAS, migrate your zone
>    file to Amazon Route53

I'm just unsure of how exactly to do this with a GoDaddy Domain. I'm not finding any alias or ANAME values in the DNS Management tabs on the GoDaddy website.

Comment: GoDaddy [doesn't offer ANAME records](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/141075/aname-record-not-accepted). Domain registrars that provide DNS services like GoDaddy often don't have the most comprehensive DNS settings. You'd need to change your nameservers to another DNS provider or CDN that offers `ANAME` records. See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html) guide from AWS and step 7, along with GoDaddy's guide on [how to edit your nameservers](https://www.godaddy.com/help/edit-my-domain-nameservers-664) there.